# Funciones recursivas python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un programa que me permita imprimir, por medio de funciones recursivas en python:

```
4444444444444444
---
33333333
---
---
2222
---
---
---
---
11
---
---
---
---
---
---
---
---
0
```

Esto es lo que intente hacer pero me da mal

```
n=4
k=1
def cam1(n):
    if(n==0):
        print("0")
    else:
        print(str(n)*2**n)
        def cam(k):
            if(k==8):
                print("---a")
            else:
                print("---",end="\n")
                cam(k+1)
        cam(k)
        cam1(n-1)
cam1(n)
```

cuando imprime en vez de imprimir lo que debería imprime en cada apartado 8 veces el "---"
¿esta mal la lógica?, o como se podría optimizar el código para que quede correcto por medio de la recursividad

Comment: de que depende la cantidad de lineas de `---`  ???

Comment: la cantidad de líneas no depende de nada, lo utilice como un ejemplo, el problema es la repetición

Comment: repetición de  qué?, cantidad de número? o qué?

Comment: la repeticion de "---" en vertical, no se como hacer la funcion para que se repita esa parte, si te das cuenta, entre el 4 y el 3 hay un "---", entre el 3 y el 2 hay 2 "---", entre el 2 y el 1 hay 4 "---", entre el 1 y el 0 hay 8 "---"

Comment: ok, entonces ya resolví tu problema, espera publico la respuesta

Comment: Te recomiendo que mejor ocupes bucles, lo veo mas practico para tu caso. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La recursividad se basa en llamadas continuas a la misma función que se está ejecutando y la llamada principal se resolverá cuando la última llamada recursiva sea finalizada y devuelva un valor para poder usarlo en la llamada posterior. Eso no significa volver a crear una función como lo que estas haciendo, simplemente debes volver a llamar a la función.

```py
n=4
k=1
def cam1(n, lines=1):
    if not n:
        print("0")
    else:
        print(str(n)*2**n)
        print("---\n"*lines)
        cam1(n-1, lines=lines*2) 
cam1(n)
```

Esto imprimirá:

```
4444444444444444
---

33333333
---
---

2222
---
---
---
---

11
---
---
---
---
---
---
---
---

0
```

Claramente queda un salto de línea más esto es debido a `---\n` que hay en el print, lo puedes solucionar creando una lista y usando el método `join` así:

```
print("\n".join(["---"]*lines))
```

Esto añadirá un salto de linea en por cada elemento de la lista excepto al último.

Comment: Tambien se puede utilizar el end="" en el print, para evitar el salto de linea adicional muchas gracias

Comment: jeje, pues sip. Un placer ayudar :D